# I need to animate a h1 but when animation is done i need to change opacity of same article

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

So i have an article with class recensie.
When i hover over this article the H1 within the article need to change font size to 45px during 0.5 seconds. When i remove my cursor the font size of the H1 needs to change to 40px during 0.25 seconds.

I used this jquery to achieve this (i believe it works accordingly)

```
$("article.recensie").hover(function(){
        $("article.recensie > h1").animate({ fontSize : '45px' }, 500);
    },
    function(){
    $("article.recensie > h1").stop().animate({ fontSize : "40px" }, 250);
    });
```

Now i need to change everything within the article to opacity 0.2 during 0.5 seconds
When the H1 is 45 px. On mouseout everything within the article needs to change back to opacity 1 within 0.25 seconds.

Hope someone can help me with this and i hope i did the H1 animation correctly.

This is the HTML i am using btw:

```
  <section class="album_reviews">
    <h2 class="sectiontitel"> Album Reviews </h2>
    <article class="recensie">
      <h1> Neil Young – A Letter Home </h1>
      <img src="Images/Albums/A_Letter_Home.jpg" alt="album_image"/>
      <p>Earlier this year, Neil Young unveiled Pono, a super-high-def audio service meant to deliver us from the sonic crimes of the earbud era. For his next act, he's released an acoustic covers set recorded at Jack White's Nashville music shop on a Voice-O-Graph--a super-low-def 1940s contraption that looks like a phone booth and sounds a few steps removed from a rusty tin can and some twine. If it's meant as some kind of joke, here's the punch line: In its perverse way, A Letter Home is one of the most enjoyable records Young has made this century.</p>
      <p> 
        <a href="http://www.rollingstone.com/music/albumreviews/a-letter-home-20140502#ixzz33g0Hq3pw"> Read more </a>
      </p>       
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="band_members">
    <h2 class="sectiontitel"> Band Members</h2>
    <article class="recensie">
      <h1> Neil Young </h1>
      <figure>
          <img src="Images/Artists/Neil_Young.jpg" alt="Macaque in the trees">
          <figcaption> Neil Young <br /> Singer Songwriter </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </article>
  </section>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Now i need to change everything within the article to opacity 0.2 during 0.5 seconds When the H1 is 45 px. On mouseout everything within the article needs to change back to opacity 1 within 0.25 seconds. As i said within the bulk of text :)

Hope someone can help me with this and i hope i did the H1 animation correctly.

Comment: That is not a question! It is a request for support/mentoring/help. Stack Overflow is a website for concrete questions about programming languages and programs, and answers to those questions; it's not a helpdesk or a forum or a chatroom. As a rule of thumb, consider whether anyone else can locate this question with Google and find it useful themselves. Cheers

Comment: Well i am sorry you see it that way. I think this is a question... A question for help yes... because i couldn't figure out how to do it and i don't have the time to google for answers so i figured just ask it here. Would be much faster. And the people who help me don't seem to mind, else they wouldn't help. But i'll consider it next time! Thanks for the advice

Comment: Whether the people who answer "helpdesk" questions "seem to mind" is of very little consequence to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the complete event of animation like this way

```
$("article.recensie").hover(function () {
        $("article.recensie > h1").animate({
            fontSize: '45px'
        }, 500, function () {
            $("article.recensie").css("opacity", "0.2");
        });
    },
    function () {
        $("article.recensie > h1").stop().animate({
            fontSize: "40px"
        }, 250, function () {
            $("article.recensie").css("opacity", "1");
        });
    });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z46fs/7/)

Comment: Aweomse, thanks a lot.. It looks like it does exactly what it needs to

Comment: Yeah i need to wait a few minutes before i can ;). Is there btw also a way to use animate for the opacity?